# ASP.NET How To Import Entity Framework from Another Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I created a prototype solution to test and debug an application I'm working on. But when creating a new solution for the release version (ASP.NET Website), I have tried adding the .edmx and .ett files to the new solution, but I cannot reference any of the classes within.

```
using (var data = new DataEntities())
```

"The type or namespace name 'DataEntities' could not be found..."

Comment: You should learn some basics like Visual studio Library project and how to add references to projects.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to add a reference to Entity Framework in the new solution via NuGet first. Once that was done, there were no issues.